# How securely store passwords for server side use?

Tags: javascript, database, encryption, ftp, password-protection

I'm looking for a secure way to store FTP passwords in a database that are usable only by specific users. The FTP details should be stored in a way that if the entire database is exposed that the FTP password isn't exposed. This probably should rely on the user's password to temporarily unencrypted the FTP password only when the user prompts for a FTP action. I'm looking for a solution that could implement this. Probably useful to add it concerns a web based application using javascript and php.

This is not about how to use salt, hashes, md5, sha1 etc. This is about securing FTP passwords that the server should be able to use e.g. connect to a FTP server with. This is simply not possible with hashes because those are only one way. Some symmetric password method should be used.

**Example use case:**

- User logs in to server
- User tells server to download file from his FTP details stored securely on the server
- Server looks up the FTP details and removes the encryption (possibly with the users password) **This question is about how you implement this step effectively**
- Server does whatever it has to do and then removes the unencrypted password

Comment: I'd recommend encrypting the credentials with a key provided by the user, and asking the user for that key each time you need to access the credentials... Any system you or I can devise where the key and data are on the same system is bound to be vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Mcrypt: http://php.net/manual/book.mcrypt.php

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** While the following no longer appears to apply to the question (which now seems to want to run an FTP action on account of a user (not connected via a universal authentication mechanism), which requires a reversible scheme), I am leaving it because I think it contains valuable information.

I recommend reading [Enough With The Rainbow Tables: What You Need To Know About Secure Password Schemes](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html).

It will likely answer a number of questions, including what salt is (how to prevent rainbow attacks), why MD5 isn't an ideal solution for a password hash (it's too fast and no longer requires a "significant crypto breakthrough"), what can happen if data is compromised (why plain-text is not stored), etc. It provides valuable insights.

I really like this quote:

> > No, really. Use someone else’s password system. Don’t build your own.

It's so true, even if tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Please read my updated question, which should clarify why this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The link is 404, here is (presumably) the same article on a different URL: [Enough With the Rainbow Tables: What You Need to Know About Secure Password Schemes](https://www.nccgroup.com/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2007/july/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-secure-password-schemes/)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is an MD5 hash.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

They are frequently used when storing passwords into a database, for further security you might also want to look into salting the password as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: MD5 is to be avoided in most situations; use SHA1 or `crypt()`

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. The idea is that you have some FTP connection details stored on the server and the user logs in and is able to use my application server to log in to the FTP server with the FTP login details stored on the server. Probably some sort of symmetric encryption can be used, but I don't know what method serves my purpose well. I will update my question to be more detailed.

Comment: @meagar, what crypt() are you refering to?

Comment: **DO NOT USE THIS ADVICE** It is _horrible_ advice! Do not use MD5 or SHA* algorithms to store any passwords ever.  See [Password Storage · OWASP Cheat Sheet Series](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html)